# All texts in HTML elements should have a new line character['\n']

Tags: javascript, html, dart

Every text value inside an HTML element needs a new line character. Here is the dart method I used to do it. However, it failed to add new lines for the given type of HTML elements. I would like to know how can I change this method which can success for all types of cases.

Thanks in advance.

Code

```dart
  dom.Element loop(dom.Element node){
    
    final List<dom.Element> elements = node.children;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){

      if(elements[i].hasContent() && elements[i].children.isEmpty){
        elements[i].innerHtml = '${elements[i].text}\n';
        continue;
      } else

      if(elements[i].children.isNotEmpty){
        loop(elements[i]);
      }
    }
   return node;
  }
```

Input HTML element

```html
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>
         test2
         <ul>
            <li>
               &nbsp;test3
               <ul>
                  <li>test4</li>
                  <li>test5</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>test6</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>test7</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Expected result

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>test1\n</li>
      <li>
         test2\n
         <ul>
            <li>
               &nbsp;test3\n
               <ul>
                  <li>test4\n</li>
                  <li>test5\n</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>test6\n</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>test7\n</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, things like `\n` and `\t` don't really work in html.
Try `<br>`

Comment: Unless this is `dart` specific, you need to use `elements[i].innerHTML` instead of `elements[i].innerHtml`

Comment: Hi @Jam,
Thanks but in my case letter I extract this text and use it for another work.
But before that, I need to add new line characters for these texts. <be> is not working at this case.

Comment: What is the actual result of the function? I see the data you are using to test and what you are expecting, but still missing what it really returns.

Comment: @RichardHenage I'm using dom.dart and it will expose only this method for me sadly.

Comment: @CNASIR,
Sorry for my mistakes. I changed the code and now it returning the same Element. Actually what I need is when I enter an element and it needs to change by adding new line characters for the text. That is my requirement.

Comment: How do you extract the text to use it in another work? In what format?

Comment: @Bman70 Like this - parse(element.innerHtml).body!.text.trim();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a javascript implementation of the answer (You can change it to dart easily)

```
function loop(node) {
    const elements = node.children
    for(const element of elements) {
        if(element.children.length > 0) loop(element)
        else if(element.textContent.length > 0) {
            element.innerHTML = element.textContent + " \\n "
        }
    }
}
```

This works except it won't change the text of a parent node. If you add \n to a parent node like li2 you will get the \n after everything including its children, there is no way to just select that initial text that I can see. You may need to do more research in that area.

The output of the above function.

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>test1\n</li>
      <li>
         test2
         <ul>
            <li>
               test3
               <ul>
                  <li>test4\n</li>
                  <li>test5\n</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>test6\n</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>test7\n</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```